# How can i save the Body data collected from Kinect 2.0 and save it in a JSON file?

Tags: c#, json.net

I am using lightbuzz library for my project. I am trying to get the data from "BodyWrapper _captureBody" and save iy in a file. The content of "_captureBody" is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z95ND.jpg)... I tried to serialize the object and then i tried to copy the content in the .Json file but here is the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPZyX.png) i got.It says I cannot Serialize or desalinize it.
Here is the small part of code :

```
if (_mode == ViewMode.Capture && _currentBody != null)
        {
            _capturedBody = _currentBody.ToBodyWrapper(); //capture the data of the current body coming from kinect.
            if (i < 1)
            {
                capturebody[i] = _capturedBody;
                i++;
            }
            if (i == 1)   //i want to save the data only once
            {

                string json = new 
                JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(_capturedBody);

                //write string to file
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\path.json", json);
            }
        }
```

You can use this link "https://vitruviuskinect.com/documentation/windows/html/e07dd042-e9f1-c9b8-2e94-c20576115f3d.htm" for reference

Answer (score 0):

Joints is a Dictionary with key JointType. As you can see in the exception, the keys need to be string or object. I think it's better if you make your own class system (with constructor with the body as argument) and then make sure it's serializable. This means that you'll need to change that property.
From own experience I try to stay away from dictionaries and JSON. Maybe convert it to a class with a Custom Joint class that has an extra property with the enum.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue myself now.
here is what i did,

I used the method ToJSON to serialize a Kinect Body object.

```
string json = body.ToJSON();   //The body contains all the Kinect generated data.
```

Then I saved the file using:

```
File.SaveAllText(json, "path-of-file.json");
```

if the above Syntax doesn't work then you can also use  to save .json file:

```
File.WriteAllText(path-of-file,json);
```

And finally to read the JSON file again I used :

```
BodyWrapper body = File.ReadAllText("path-of-file.json").ToBodyWrapper();
```

Thanks for the help anyway... :-)